# Store partial result of ssh command in array

Tags: arrays, bash, variables, ssh, arr

Hi lets say I have the following servers:

- server1:

1. `/root/script.sh`

- server2:

1. `root/folder1`
2. `root/folder1/file1.log`
3. `root/folder1/file2.log`
4. `root/folder1/file3.log`

When I call (from server1) `script.sh` I have the following which works okay and will print the list of files in folder 1:

```
server2="1245@server2"
    
array=(
    $(
        ssh $server2"
            ls folder1
        "
    )
)
    
if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
    log "SUCCESSFULLY retrieved list of files from $server2. Proceed. . . "
else
    log "FAILED while retrieving files from $server2. Exit with error. . . "
    exit 1
fi

printf '%s\n' "${array[@]}"
```

Result of array:

```
file1.log
file2.log
file3.log
```

---

But, I what I want to do is the following:

1. Execute `script.sh` from `server1`
2. Open `ssh connection` to `server2`
3. Check if directory `folder1` exists
4. If exists store list of files from `folder1` to an `array` that will be later on used in `script.sh`
5. Else store 0 in `array`
6. Close ssh connection
7. Check if previous ssh request was successful
8. Print array
9. Use array

```
server2="1245@server2"
    
array=(
    $(
        ssh $server2"
        
            #do something else
            #do other stuff
        
            if find folder1 -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 | read; then
                echo ""Directory folder1 is not empty and contains x files"" #dont store in array this echo
                #STORE ONLY THIS IN ARRAY - ONLY IN CASE DIR EXISTS AND NOT EMPTY
                ls folder1
            else
                echo 'Directory folder1 is empty'
            fi
            
            #do something else
            #do other stuff
        "
    )
)
    
if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
    log "SUCCESSFULLY retrieved list of files from $server2. Proceed. . . "
else
    log "FAILED while retrieving files from $server2. Exit with error. . . "
    exit 1
fi

printf '%s\n' "${array[@]}"
```

Comment: The main part of the question is that I want to store only partial part of ssh command into array instead of results of the entire ssh command

Comment: Why have the ssh call run `echo` commands (to print strings to stdout) if you're just going to discard them before populating the array? I'm *assuming* what you really want is to display some of the ssh call to stdout/terminal, perhaps save some info to a log file *and* save some of the ssh call results to an array; I'd suggest  you run the ssh call by itself (ie, not wrapped in a `$(...)` and not wrapped in a pair of array parens), capture all output (stderr and stdout) to a file, then process the file as needed ... display to terminal, write to log and/or save to array

Comment: it gets more complicated with the additional ssh commands (`do something else`, `do other stuff`); what if some of these generate output you don't want stored in the array? what if some of these generate errors? I get the feeling the ssh call is rather complicated which in turn could require 'extra' post-processing before determining what, if any, of the results of the ssh call should be stored in an array; again, I'd suggest you split your operation into separate chunks ... ssh call and store results in file, post process file for messages and errors, populate array

Comment: So you suggest I should open SSH read directory and store results in file.

Then Open again an SSH to read file and store to array?

Comment: Also would be heavy. Let's say I have 100000 files 1GB each

Comment: where did *`read file and store to array`* come from? nothing in your description or code suggests you're reading files ... the only thing I see is storing the results of the `ls` in an array

Comment: in the 2nd half of your question you have a lengthy set of code being run by the ssh call; I'm suggesting you make that same, single call but store all output (stdout, stderr) to a file, process that file for messages and errors, then extract the `ls` info to populate the array

Comment: what does the *`100000 files 1GB each`* have to do with this question ... I'm assuming the `ls` would return a list of 100K files that you want to store in an array (though that brings up questions of what exactly are you going to do with 100K array entries?!?!?!);  or are you trying to pull the contents of those 100K files across the network (which doesn't appear to be addressed anywhere in your question)?

Answer (score 0):

Have you thought of directing the "report" (ls ?) you want to capture to stdout, and any other messaging of informational nature (echo) to stderr, the save the 2 streams to separate files ?